# Running regressions and extract model estimates to a dataframe in R

Tags: r, linear-regression

I have 3 exposure variables `x1-x3`, 10 outcome variables `y1-y10` and 3 covariates `cv1-cv3`.

I would like to regress each outcome on each exposure adjusted for all covariates. Then I would like model estimates i.e. beta, SE, p-value placed in a dataframe. Is there a way to automate this in R. Thank you!

The models i want to run look like this:

```
y1 ~ x1+cv1+cv2+cv3 ... y10 ~ x1+cv1+cv2+cv3

y1 ~ x2+cv1+cv2+cv3 ... y10 ~ x2+cv1+cv2+cv3

y1 ~ x3+cv1+cv2+cv3 ... y10 ~ x3+cv1+cv2+cv3
```

Comment: Yes, there is a way, but can you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/2572423). What's your data look like? What's the current format? Can you `dput` it's output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without data and a reproducible example, it is hard to help you, but here's an example with simulated data. First, create a fake dataset, called `data`:

```
library(tidyverse)

make_df <- function(y_i) {
  data_frame(y_var = y_i, y_i = rnorm(100),
              x1 = rnorm(100),  x2 = rnorm(100),  x3 = rnorm(100),
             cv1 = runif(100), cv2 = runif(100), cv3 = runif(100))
}

ys <- paste0("Y_", sprintf("%02d", 1:10))
ys
#>  [1] "Y_01" "Y_02" "Y_03" "Y_04" "Y_05" "Y_06" "Y_07" "Y_08" "Y_09" "Y_10"

data <-
ys %>%
  map_dfr(make_df)

data
#> # A tibble: 1,000 x 8
#>    y_var    y_i      x1      x2      x3    cv1     cv2    cv3
#>    <chr>  <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>
#>  1 Y_01   0.504  0.892  -0.806  -1.56   0.145  0.436   0.701 
#>  2 Y_01   0.967  1.24   -1.19    0.920  0.866  0.00100 0.567 
#>  3 Y_01  -0.824 -0.729  -0.0855 -1.06   0.0665 0.780   0.471 
#>  4 Y_01   0.294  2.37   -0.514  -0.955  0.397  0.0462  0.209 
#>  5 Y_01  -0.893  0.0298  0.0369  0.0787 0.640  0.709   0.0485
#>  6 Y_01   0.670 -0.347   1.56    2.11   0.843  0.542   0.793 
#>  7 Y_01  -1.59   1.04    0.228   0.573  0.185  0.151   0.558 
#>  8 Y_01  -2.04   0.289  -0.435  -0.113  0.833  0.0898  0.653 
#>  9 Y_01  -0.637  0.818  -0.454   0.606  0.294  0.378   0.315 
#> 10 Y_01  -1.61  -0.628  -2.75    1.06   0.353  0.0863  0.332 
#> # ... with 990 more rows
```

At this point, you have options. One way is to use the `group_by` %>% `do(tidy(*))` recipe:

```
data %>%
  gather(x_var, x_value, -c(y_var, y_i, cv1:cv3)) %>%
  group_by(y_var, x_var) %>%
  do(broom::tidy(lm(y_i ~ x_value + cv1 + cv2 + cv3, data = .)))
#> # A tibble: 150 x 7
#> # Groups:   y_var, x_var [30]
#>    y_var x_var term        estimate std.error statistic p.value
#>    <chr> <chr> <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
#>  1 Y_01  x1    (Intercept)  -0.111      0.344   -0.324    0.747
#>  2 Y_01  x1    x_value      -0.0440     0.111   -0.396    0.693
#>  3 Y_01  x1    cv1           0.286      0.372    0.769    0.444
#>  4 Y_01  x1    cv2           0.0605     0.379    0.160    0.873
#>  5 Y_01  x1    cv3          -0.0690     0.378   -0.182    0.856
#>  6 Y_01  x2    (Intercept)  -0.146      0.336   -0.434    0.665
#>  7 Y_01  x2    x_value       0.117      0.105    1.12     0.265
#>  8 Y_01  x2    cv1           0.287      0.362    0.793    0.430
#>  9 Y_01  x2    cv2           0.0564     0.376    0.150    0.881
#> 10 Y_01  x2    cv3           0.0125     0.379    0.0330   0.974
#> # ... with 140 more rows
```

Another approach is to use a `split` variable and then a `map` function from `purrr`:

```
data %>%
  gather(x_var, x_value, -c(y_var, y_i, cv1:cv3)) %>%
  mutate(y_var_x_var = paste0(y_var, x_var)) %>%
  split(.$y_var_x_var) %>%
  map(~ lm(y_i ~ x_value + cv1 + cv2 + cv3, data = .))
#> $Y_01x1
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = y_i ~ x_value + cv1 + cv2 + cv3, data = .)
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#> (Intercept)      x_value          cv1          cv2          cv3  
#>    -0.11144     -0.04396      0.28585      0.06051     -0.06896  
#> 
#> 
#> $Y_01x2
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = y_i ~ x_value + cv1 + cv2 + cv3, data = .)
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#> (Intercept)      x_value          cv1          cv2          cv3  
#>    -0.14562      0.11732      0.28726      0.05642      0.01249  
#> 
#> 
# ...and so on...
#> 
#> 
#> $Y_10x2
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = y_i ~ x_value + cv1 + cv2 + cv3, data = .)
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#> (Intercept)      x_value          cv1          cv2          cv3  
#>    -0.45689     -0.02530      0.61375      0.34377     -0.02357  
#> 
#> 
#> $Y_10x3
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = y_i ~ x_value + cv1 + cv2 + cv3, data = .)
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#> (Intercept)      x_value          cv1          cv2          cv3  
#>    -0.44423     -0.18377      0.64739      0.27688     -0.02013
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your help JasonAizkalns. I like the group_by %>% do(tidy(*)) recipe. I have a follow-up question please - how would you extend this approach to deal with different variable names. For example say you had 4 y-variables called 'weight' 'height' 'bmi' 'fat mass'... and similarly different names for x-variables and covariables. I guess you would include some kind of loop in the code?

Comment: @AhmedElhakeem First, I would use "search" - sounds like a pretty standard question, so someone may have already answered it. Then, if you still need help, I would ask a new question, but make sure you make your question reproducible (or make some fake data) so that others can help you. Be sure to include what you have tried (coded) already and exactly where you are getting stuck.